# How do I pass props ID to another component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3

This is my admin panel component. Where I create form with recipe name and an ID. I want to display it in another panel but I do not know how do I pass the ID to another component to display the data. The id is uuid in json.

I get this error in my other panel

```
{"recipe_id":["invalid"]}
```

```
props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      setId: "recipe/setId",
      setName: "recipe/setName",
      fetch: "recipe/fetch",
      reset: "recipe/reset",
      persist: "recipe/persist",
    }),
    onSubmit(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      this.persist().then(({ data }) => {
        this.setId(data.id);
        this.$emit("onSaved");
      });
    },
```

This is how i fetch the recipe in different panel

```
...mapActions({
      fetchRecipe: "recipe/fetch",

})

mounted()
 this.fetchRecipe().then((data) => {
      this.recipeItems = response.data
    });
```

Comment: save the id in you data object and then pass a prop to your another component like

    <Other-Component :id="id"/>

and then in other component do

    props:{
      id:{
         type:string,
      }
    }

    <p>{{props.id}}</p>

Comment: But How Can I do this, i am returning an array and passing to recipeItems. This is not component but array

Comment: can u provide more details about the component you want to pass the id to and where you get the error

Comment: I pass from admin panel, to different web panel, recipe id and name. I want to display the recipe name as list of array in my table.  But it's not working because there is no id